# CoreData object is fetched in the correct order, but nested objects are un-ordered

Tags: swift, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have the following code to fetch `Person` object from CoreData model:

```
let fr:NSFetchRequest<Person> = Person.fetchRequest()
let sd = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: false)
fr.sortDescriptors = [sd]
let persons = try? dataController.context.fetch(fr)
```

This works fine, and I get an array of `[Person]` in the right order (by name).

```
let children = persons[0].children    // children set is in random order
```

However, each person has multiple `Child` objects. These are fetched automatically with each `Person`, however, these `Child` objects are not sorted. They come in random order.

How can I control the order in which these `Child` objects are fetched?

Edit: I am aware that I can order the nested objects manually after being fetched from CoreData, but I am reluctant to do that since that would not be efficient and would cause faulting on all child objects. I am looking for a way that lets CoreData fetch the child objects in a certain order.

Comment: I am not sure if that's possible . however why not ordering them after fetching ?

Comment: @MohmmadS I can iterate through the objects and order them, but that would cause faulting and overhead, especially if I may not access all of the child elements

Comment: `.sort` wont be enough ?, + since person object get fetched each time you iterate inside the array the childs would be feteched already when you're sitting on the element index, so i think `.sort` would be enough, however no harm from trying .

Comment: Objects in a Set are always unordered so I am not sure what you are expecting? To sort them you need to create an array from your Set object and sort the array.

Comment: Perhaps you want to do a fetch request on the Child entity, and sort that according to parent.name and (child) name.